# How to get back the converted Time zone value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I am converting a datetime value to Indian Standard Time using the below code:

```
public DateTime GetdatetimedetailsinIST(DateTime datetimeinfo, String timeoffsetvalue)
{
    string offset= timeoffsetvalue;
    string timeZoneFormat = Convert.ToString("India Standard Time");
    string strIndianTimezone = timeZoneFormat;
    TimeZoneInfo tzinfoIndian = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(strIndianTimezone);
    DateTime dtDateTime = datetimeinfo.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(offset));//ToUniversalTime();
    dtDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dtDateTime, tzinfoIndian);
    return dtDateTime;
}
```

Now I am calling `GetdatetimedetailsinIST(5/6/2014 8:00:00 AM,"240");`

and it will reurn Indian Time 5/6/2014 5:30:00 PM.

Now I want to get back the 5/6/2014 8:00:00 AM for another scenario by using value 5/6/2014 5:30:00 PM.

What are the changes need to do in the above function?

Please help.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Just at a quick glance, `GetdatetimedetailsinIST("5/6/2014 5:30:00 PM", "-240")` should work correctly, without any code changes.

Comment: No, it will not work :( I have tried so.

Answer (score 0):

howeverCould you add a string timeZoneToConvertTo parameter to your convert method?

```
public static DateTime DateTimeConvert(DateTime nonConvertedDateTime, string timeoffsetvalue, string timeZoneToConvertTo)
    {
        TimeZoneInfo tzinfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneToConvertTo);
        DateTime dtDateTime = nonConvertedDateTime.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(timeoffsetvalue));
        dtDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dtDateTime, tzinfo);
        return dtDateTime;
    }

Console.WriteLine(DateTimeConvert(new DateTime(2014, 5, 6, 8, 00, 00), "240", "India Standard Time").ToString());

Console.WriteLine(DateTimeConvert(new DateTime(2014, 5, 6, 8, 00, 00), "240", "Central Standard Time").ToString());
```

You still need to handle any exceptions resulting from an inability to find the timezone.

I don't understand why you want an offset instead of using the ToUniversal() extension, however, that is your choice.

Comment: what about this line  DateTime dtDateTime = nonConvertedDateTime.AddMinutes(Convert.ToInt32(timeoffsetvalue)); ?

Comment: Should I need to do -240 ?

Comment: If you want to do an offset by minutes, that is what I would do. I don't know enough to answer the significance of "240" to this problem to answer much more specifically than that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding minutes manually is seldom required or recommended.  Also, there are a lot of unnecessary strings floating around your method.  Consider the following instead:

```
public static DateTime ConvertToIndiaTime(DateTime dateTime, int offsetMinutes)
{
    // Create a DateTimeOffset from the input values.
    // This assumes positive offset values are *WEST* of UTC,
    // such as if it came from the getTimeZoneOffset function of
    // JavaScript's Date object.
    TimeSpan offset = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(-offsetMinutes);
    DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(dateTime, offset);

    // Convert the DateTimeOffset to the desired time zone
    DateTimeOffset converted =
        TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(dto, "Indian Standard Time");

    // Return the DateTime portion, representing the local time in India.
    return converted.DateTime;
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
// get a DateTime object
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("5/6/2014 8:00:00 AM",
                                  "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// get the offset as an integer
int offsetMinutes = 240;

// call the conversion method
DateTime indiaTime = ConvertToIndiaTime(dt, offsetMinutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method seems to combine two separate `DateTime` operations into one - hence it's not easy for you to reverse the operation. How about the following structure:

```
private static readonly TimeZoneInfo IstTimeZone =
   TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");

public static DateTime ConvertDateTimeUtcToIst(DateTime toConvert)
{
   return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(toConvert, IstTimeZone);
}

public static DateTime ConvertDateTimeIstToUtc(DateTime toConvert)
{
   return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(toConvert, IstTimeZone);
}
```

Usage:

```
var converted = ConvertDateTimeUtcToIst(DateTime.Parse("5/6/2014 8:00:00 AM"))
                   .AddMinutes(240);
var reverted = ConvertDateTimeIstToUtc(converted).AddMinutes(-240);
```

Or if you absolutely need to have it in one method:

```
public static DateTime ConvertDateTimeUtcToIst(
                          DateTime toConvert, int offset = 0)
{
   return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(toConvert, IstTimeZone)
             .AddMinutes(offset);
}

public static DateTime ConvertDateTimeIstToUtc(
                          DateTime toConvert, int offset = 0)
{
   return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(toConvert, IstTimeZone)
             .AddMinutes(offset);
}
```

Usage:

```
var converted = ConvertDateTimeUtcToIst(
                   DateTime.Parse("5/6/2014 8:00:00 AM"), 240);
var reverted = ConvertDateTimeIstToUtc(converted, -240);
```